# Not sure how to reorder x-axis labels on matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code. I am trying plot a graph.

Currently, the x-axis is not labelled in ascending order: 28-37.99 should come before 38-47.99 but I am not sure how to do this.

Would be so grateful for a helping hand!

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,figsize=(15, 15))
fig.tight_layout(pad=10)

newerdf = newdf.copy()
bins = [18,28,38,48,58]
names = ['<28','28-37.99','38-47.99','48-57.99','58+']
d = dict(enumerate(names, 1))
newerdf['age'] = np.digitize(newerdf['age'], bins)
newerdf['age'] = newerdf['age'].map(d)
Graph1 = sns.lineplot(data=newerdf,x="age", y="distance",errorbar ='se',err_style='bars',ax=axes[0])
Graph2 = sns.lineplot(data=newerdf,x="age", y="duration",errorbar ='se',err_style='bars',ax=axes[1])
Graph1.set_xlabel( "Age",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
Graph2.set_xlabel( "Age",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
Graph1.set_ylabel("Wayfinding Distance",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
Graph2.set_ylabel("Wayfinding Duration",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that it seems that seaborn is misinterpreting the order of the given axis. I would recommend exchange to matplotlib. And use fixed locators

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is that the x_axis in seaborn is not capable of interpreting the given order of the data

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,figsize=(15, 15))


bins = [18,28,38,48,58]
names = ['<28','28-37.99','38-47.99','48-57.99','58+']
loc_x_axis = np.arange(0,len(names))
ax.plot(loc_x_axis,your_y_data)
# Tip try to ensure that the given y data is ordered accordingly to what you want, so ensure the ytick matchs the xtick location
# This will create your plot, without labels

ax.set_xticks(loc_x_axis,names)
# To set labels accordingly to your wanted arrangement
```

Comment: Should the ax.plot part not be ax.plot(your_x_data, your_y_data)?

Comment: In this case, no. You just want to ensure the given x axis from what I could see.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I want the error bars to be plotted automatically (as they are in seaborn) but you have to manually specify in ax.plot - hence why I preferred the former method! :(

Comment: Is there a way I can reorder the x-axis on seaborn?

Comment: I mean seaborn basically works around your given data. Why dont you try sort_values() the given arrays

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - I have created a new thread to address this :)